# Is it fine to ask questions about boot errors from log files?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm looking into the log files and search for boot error messages. When I find an error I search it on the Internet.

If I don't find any solution, is it fine to ask a question about how to fix it?

I know that bug reports are off-topic on the site, but how far can I go into this side? Probably I don't know if the error is a bug of the platform or just a problem that I can fix getting instructions.

Comment: Even fixing bugs is not off topic, AFAIK. So go ahead and ask, and let the community decide. even if it gets closed, you might get some valuable help.

Comment: @muru Yes, I already adopted this method. :-)

Comment: It seems to depend on the complexity of the bug report. If there is an easy fix you will get an answer. If you post incomplete information or it is complex it tends to get closed as off topic. IMHO filing a bug report is preferable as it results in actual fixes which helps everyone, so I tend to close them. But this is why questions are closed (and re-opened) by community consensus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think bodhi hit the nail in his comment:

> IMHO filing a bug report is preferable as it results in **actual fixes which helps everyone**, so I tend to close them.

If there´s a solution that gets rid of the problem from the bud, heck, report a bug! Not everything has to be in Ask Ubuntu, nor solved by Ask Ubuntu. Heck, I´m quite glad that a bug I solved [answering a question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/130779/41104) was solved [for everyone else](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/130779/41104). It stripped all usefulness of my answer, but in the long run, it was for the best, since nobody else will *ever* face the same problem as OP.

Before asking a question, or answering one my first concern is: is possible that this problem can be solved before people even face it? If the answer for that is yes, then I would follow whatever is necessary to solve it, and asking a question in the site is rarely (I would say, never) the course of action for this propose.

Now, about "boot logs errors", if your system don´t present a problem, I wouldn´t try to even "fix" them. There´s a culture for developers to ignore these messages because most of them are "solve" later on while booting, like loading drm/dri modules earlier using KMS prevents certain "errors" to show. The fact that you can´t find relevant information in Internet just further support this.

If you want to know "why" a message appears, yeah, why not. Now "fix it", only invites people with unrelated problems that for some reason have similar or the same message, which is unrelated to their problems and the solution they give, just making noise.

If your question just degrade the signal to noise ratio, by all means, don´t ask it.